# How to delete webparts from the main page in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have the following code which adds a webpart, but i need some way to delete all the webparts before this runs.  Anybody know how to do this?  I have tried multiple ways, but am brand new to powershell and sharepoint and have no idea what i am doing.

```
    $wpm = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    $sortedNodes = $pageXml.Module.File.AllUsersWebPart | sort { $_.WebPartZoneID, [int] $_.WebPartOrder }  

    write-host $sortedNodes
    write-host $sortedNodes.Count

    foreach ($webPartXml in $sortedNodes)
    {
        $zoneId = $webPartXml.WebPartZoneID
        $zoneIndex = $webPartXml.WebPartOrder
        $xml = $webPartXml.InnerText

        $wpd = $wpm.ImportWebPart($xml)
        $wpd = $wpm.AddWebPart($wpd.WebPart, $zoneId, $zoneIndex)

        "Adding a web part to the [$zoneId] zone, [$zoneIndex] position..."

        try
        {
            Submit-ExecuteQuery $context
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "The following error occurred while trying to add the web part: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```js
$wpm = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

<# Remove All Webparts  - Begin #>

 foreach ($webPart in $wpm.WebParts)
  {
     
   $wpdD = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.WebPartDefinition
            $context.Load($webPart)
   $wpdD = $webPart
   $wpdD.DeleteWebPart();

   try
   {
    Submit-ExecuteQuery $context
   }
   catch
   {
    Write-Host "The following error occurred while trying to add the web part: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
   }
  }
  
<# Remove All Webparts  - End #>

    $sortedNodes = $pageXml.Module.File.AllUsersWebPart | sort { $_.WebPartZoneID, [int] $_.WebPartOrder }  

    write-host $sortedNodes
    write-host $sortedNodes.Count

    foreach ($webPartXml in $sortedNodes)
    {
        $zoneId = $webPartXml.WebPartZoneID
        $zoneIndex = $webPartXml.WebPartOrder
        $xml = $webPartXml.InnerText

        $wpd = $wpm.ImportWebPart($xml)
        $wpd = $wpm.AddWebPart($wpd.WebPart, $zoneId, $zoneIndex)

        "Adding a web part to the [$zoneId] zone, [$zoneIndex] position..."

        try
        {
            Submit-ExecuteQuery $context
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "The following error occurred while trying to add the web part: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing one line of code above the submit-executequery - $context.Load($webPart) - but other than that, it works great!